# Should chat rooms "Ruby/Rails" and "Ruby on Rails" be merged?

Tags: discussion, chat

While scanning for an appropriate chat room to go to, I found the following rooms:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24/ruby-rails

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5676/ruby-on-rails

To me those two chat rooms seem to be identical and I suggest that those two rooms be merged into one.

Comment: Perhaps you should chat with the room owners and convince them to ask the moderators to do the merge.  If the owners feel they are different enough, it might not be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong in having two different chat rooms with apparently a similar purpose; the "[Create gallery chat rooms](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/gallery-chat-rooms)" privilege page says:

> #### When should I create a gallery chat room?
>
> When you wish to have a controlled conversation between specific community members, without anyone else interjecting.

As Adam Davis says in his comment, you can talk to the room owners, and see if you can convince them to ask the chat rooms be merged. I don't think merging the rooms should be forced, though.